# I would like to improve my question reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation

I asked a question on the Blender Stack Exchange that received many downvotes.  I think it is because I was making more of a "request" without showing I had worked on the problem myself.  I truthfully did not have any idea how to start!  The answer is very helpful and I learned from it, and i am sure others will continue to benefit from it.  I care about my reputation and would like to somehow undo my negative score on that question.  Can this be done?

Thank you!

Comment: You would be better to answer questions and ask questions than to worry about a past few negative points.  One day you will receive more points than expected for some action.  Its very entertaining that for larger Stack Exchange sites people can earn 300 points for a single question.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger  Thank you for encouragement !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assuming you are referring to: [How to make glowing particles, with a solid glowing center](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/50564/2217). Well there is not much you can do to change the votes on that question now.
You could edit it to make it a bit clearer what you mean, specify that you are looking for the particle and material settings to make that particle effect.

Yet even then the people who originally DVed probably won't be back to your question to change their votes.

However you shouldn't get too bothered by the down votes. You lost 6 rep from the three DVs, but gained 5 from the one UV, and two more from accepting the answer. So net on that question you actually **gained** one rep (so far).

I personally don't know why that question got so many DVs. We have had many others that simply ask how to do X, and are well received. For example:
[How can I make a wrought iron basket?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/30796/2217)
[How to animate morphing a rectangular plane into a sphere](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/24043/2217)
[How did I make this soccer-ball/honeycomb shape?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/46346/2217)
[How to make a jelly material?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/32466/2217)

So in the end, no there is no way to "really undo" the negative rep.